# Error in dplyr Mutate - looping through columns to produce graphs

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm working on RStudio trying to loop through a few lines of dplyr-ggplot script which identifies outliers, then makes a plot and labels the outliers. A subset of the data looks like:

```
    miR_373 miR_30 miR_182        type
C1     6.78  -2.88    3.75     control
C2    11.88   0.28    7.26     control
C3     8.55  -4.08    3.37     control
C4     7.60  -2.76    7.60     control
C5    13.18   2.33   13.18     control
P18   12.62   0.37    7.99     treated
P19    4.60  -7.62   -0.52     treated
P23    9.72   0.07    9.72     treated
P24   10.40  -0.68   10.40     treated
P25   11.08   0.81   11.08     treated
N20    7.35  -4.29    2.48 non_treated
N21    3.06  -2.21    4.59 non_treated
N22    6.05  -4.99    2.15 non_treated
N28   10.44  -0.15   10.44 non_treated
N29   10.59   0.36   10.59 non_treated
```

The below script works fine to produce one plot:

```
cts <- as.data.frame(read.csv("c:/Users/dat.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))
is_outlier <- function(x) {
  return(x< quantile(x,0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x>quantile(x,0.75) +1.5 * IQR(x))
}

dat <- cts %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(is_outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(miR_373), miR_373, as.numeric(NA)))
dat$outlier[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)

ggplot(dat, aes(y=miR_373, x=factor(type))) + geom_boxplot() + geom_text(aes(label=outlier),na.rm=TRUE,hjust=0.05) + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1, binwidth = .5)
```

producing

[image]

But the below code doesn't work to loop through variables (columns):

```
miRs <- names(cts)[c(1,2,3)]
for(i in miRs){
  dat2 <- cts %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(is_outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(i), i, as.numeric(NA)))
  dat2$outlier[which(is.na(dat2$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)

  ggplot(dat2, aes(y=i, x=factor(type))) + geom_boxplot() + geom_text(aes(label=outlier),na.rm=TRUE,hjust=0.05) + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1, binwidth = .5)
}
```

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

I can tell that my substitution of i in the loop isn't accepted but I don't know why and haven't found another way to do it. Any suggestions or further reading would be appreciated.

Comment: I think using ```purrr``` package is the best way to loop through lists, vectors or columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programming with `tidyverse` packages takes some getting used to. In this case, you are treating `i` as though it were an expression, when in fact it is a string. You can convert it to `quosure` and then unquote it when you need it, like this:

```
for(i in miRs){
    i <- rlang::parse_expr(i)
    dat2 <- cts %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column(var="outlier") %>%
        group_by(type) %>%
        mutate(is_outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(!!i),
                                 !!i,
                                 as.numeric(NA)))
    dat2$outlier[which(is.na(dat2$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)
    dev.new()
    p <- ggplot(dat2, aes(y=!!i, x=factor(type))) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        geom_text(aes(label=outlier),
                  na.rm=TRUE,
                  hjust=0.05) +
        geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',
                     stackdir='center',
                     dotsize=1,
                     binwidth = .5)
    print(p)
}
```